# bash append string from socket

Tags: bash

```
lines=""
for (( i=0; i < $lineNum; i++ )); do
  read -t 1 -u $redis_socket line
  lines+=$line
done
echo "$lines"
```

for example, suppose each line from socket is `aaa`, `bbbb`, `ccccc` I want final output to be like `aaabbbbccccc`.

but I got `aaabc`, am I doing something wrong here?

I did try many alternatives in other questions but nothing really works.

sample output lines are like below

```
redis_version:3.0.7
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
slave0:ip=127.0.0.1,port=6379,state=online,offset=549974442474,lag=0
....
db1:keys=4190,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
```

and the final output is

```
db1:keys=4190,expires=0,avg_ttl=0tl=1200913396e,offset=549974442474,lag=0
```

Comment: Just say `var="$var new value"`.

Comment: yea..in this example lines="$lines$line", it results in same undesired output

Comment: edited, I don't think this one is duplicate of what is suggested above.

Comment: This is weird. It looks like the string you are getting has some kind of `\r` that makes string appending to start from the beginning instead.

Comment: Can you try saying `line=$(echo "line" | tr -d '\r')`?

Comment: oh my gosh.. it does include a carriage return for every single line, thanks it was so helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the comments, the problem lies in the carriage return of the output you are getting.

Since `$line` contains a carriage return, given a value, saying `lines+=$line` you are getting as a result the intersection of `$lines` and `$line`, instead of having `$line` appended to `$lines`.

```
line       lines
XXX        XXX
YYYY       XXXY
ZZ         XXXY
```

With your examples:

```
line  -> redis_git_dirty:0
lines -> redis_git_dirty:0

line  -> slave0:ip=127.0.0.1,port=6379,state=online,offset=549974442474,lag=0
lines -> redis_git_dirty:0.1,port=6379,state=online,offset=549974442474,lag=0
#        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#           intersection

line  -> db1:keys=4190,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
lines -> db1:keys=4190,expires=0,avg_ttl=0te=online,offset=549974442474,lag=0
#        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#           intersection
```

etc.

So the solution is to remove this carriage return beforehand:

```
line=$(echo "line" | tr -d '\r')
lines+="$line"
```